# YAML comparison using deepdiff - exclude_paths formatting not working

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, deep-diff

We are using DeepDiff for comparing two YAML files and then wanted to exclude certain paths for comparison

- File1 dataset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp1
  labels:
    app: myapp
    env: prod
    customer: A
```

- File2 dataset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp2
  labels:
    app: myapp
    env: dev
    customer: B
```

My code i tried, but the exclude_paths are not working as intended

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

# Unfortunately the exclude_paths is forced on us from a separate team in below format
exclude_paths = ["metadata.labels.env", "metadata.labels.annotation"]

print(DeepDiff(test1, test2, ignore_order=True, exclude_paths=exclude_paths))
```

Unfortunately the exclude_paths is forced on us from a separate team in a text file and we convert that to a list

```
    with open(args.exeception_list) as f:
        exp = f.read().splitlines()
```

which makes into below format

```
exclude_paths = ["metadata.labels.env", "metadata.labels.annotation"]
```

If i change the `exclude_paths` to below format it works

```
exclude_paths = ["['metadata']['labels']['env']", "['metadata']['labels']['annotation']"]
```

I couldn't find an easy way to convert dot notation to 'square bracket & single quote' format.

Any better approaches rather than converting the `metadata.labels.env` to `['metadata']['labels']['env']` in a convoluted manner? thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what's *easy* or *convoluted*. If you want to ask about simplifying your code, you need to show that code and tell us the relevant metric (e.g. lines of code, algorithmic complexity, …).